# No audio when webrtc mobile clients connected in different network

Tags: webrtc, freeswitch, webrtc-android, mod-verto

In my current project ,we are using webrtc to connect two mobile clients in android.
We are using socket signaling to exchange data between two mobile clients.
We were able to connect peer to peer  audio and video call in android mobile clients in same and different network.
Now we changed socket signaling to verto module signalling of freeswitch so that we can make pstn call using webrtc.
After using verto module of freeswitch as signaling,we are able to make pstn call successfully.
Now when trying for peer to peer call using verto module,we are able to successfully exchange media between two verto android mobile clients.
We are able to hear audio flow between two android mobile clients when they are present in same network.
But we are not able to hear audio when two android mobile clients are in different network.
Only observation from logs is ice candidate failed in negative case scenario.
We are using same stun and turn server for app to app call in same network too.

Log for non working flow

```
2020-10-31 17:23:01.390 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev V/WebRtcCallService: registerTelephonyCallListener()
2020-10-31 17:23:01.393 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: create@[name=main, id=2]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.393 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: constructor
2020-10-31 17:23:01.394 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: start
2020-10-31 17:23:01.406 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: HEADSET profile state: DISCONNECTED
2020-10-31 17:23:01.406 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: Bluetooth proxy for headset profile has started
2020-10-31 17:23:01.406 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: start done: BT state=2
2020-10-31 17:23:01.413 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev I/WebRtcCallService: Service started#onStartCommand :MAKE_CALL_PSTN
2020-10-31 17:23:01.414 27928-28653/com.mirrorfly.dev I/WebRtcCallService: call type assigned: audio
2020-10-31 17:23:01.434 27928-28653/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglBase14: SDK version: 28. isEGL14Supported: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.437 27928-28653/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRtcCallService: init() -- initializing the web rtc instance 
2020-10-31 17:23:01.439 27928-28653/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRtcUtils: [stun:stun.contus.us]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.444 27928-28653/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRtcUtils: turn:stun.contus.us:3478
2020-10-31 17:23:01.449 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: MessagingClient: created!!
2020-10-31 17:23:01.449 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: NativeLibrary: Native library has already been loaded.
2020-10-31 17:23:01.459 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: ctor@[name=Thread-12, id=3914]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.460 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: Sample rate is set to 48000 Hz
2020-10-31 17:23:01.460 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: canUseAcousticEchoCanceler: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.461 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: canUseNoiseSuppressor: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.462 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev W/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: AAudio support is currently disabled on all devices!
2020-10-31 17:23:01.463 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: Android SDK: 28, Release: 9, Brand: xiaomi, Device: sakura_india, Id: PKQ1.180917.001, Hardware: qcom, Manufacturer: Xiaomi, Model: Redmi 6 Pro, Product: sakura_india
2020-10-31 17:23:01.466 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: Audio State: audio mode: MODE_NORMAL, has mic: true, mic muted: false, music active: false, speakerphone: false, BT SCO: false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.466 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: Audio State: 
2020-10-31 17:23:01.466 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   fixed volume=false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.468 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   STREAM_VOICE_CALL: volume=5, max=5, muted=false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.476 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   STREAM_MUSIC: volume=15, max=15, muted=false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.481 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   STREAM_RING: volume=4, max=15, muted=false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.483 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   STREAM_ALARM: volume=15, max=15, muted=false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.489 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   STREAM_NOTIFICATION: volume=4, max=15, muted=false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.494 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   STREAM_SYSTEM: volume=4, max=15, muted=false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.499 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCProximitySensor: AppRTCProximitySensor@[name=main, id=2]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.499 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCProximitySensor: start@[name=main, id=2]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.500 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCProximitySensor: Proximity sensor: name=LTR579 ALSPS, vendor: LiteOn, power: 0.095, resolution: 0.0, max range: 5.000305, min delay: 0, type: android.sensor.proximity, max delay: 65535000, reporting mode: 1, isWakeUpSensor: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.500 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: Audio Devices: 
2020-10-31 17:23:01.501 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE(out): channels=[1], encodings=[2], sample rates=[48000], id=2
2020-10-31 17:23:01.501 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER(out): channels=[2], encodings=[2], sample rates=[48000], id=3
2020-10-31 17:23:01.502 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   TYPE_TELEPHONY(out): channels=[1, 2], encodings=[2], sample rates=[8000, 16000], id=10
2020-10-31 17:23:01.503 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   TYPE_BUILTIN_MIC(in): channels=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], encodings=[2], sample rates=[8000, 11025, 12000, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000], id=16
2020-10-31 17:23:01.504 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   TYPE_BUILTIN_MIC(in): channels=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], encodings=[2], sample rates=[8000, 11025, 12000, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000], id=17
2020-10-31 17:23:01.504 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   TYPE_FM_TUNER(in): channels=[1, 2], encodings=[2], sample rates=[8000, 11025, 12000, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000], id=13
2020-10-31 17:23:01.505 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager:   TYPE_TELEPHONY(in): channels=[1, 2], encodings=[2], sample rates=[8000, 11025, 12000, 16000, 22050, 24000, 32000, 44100, 48000], id=14
2020-10-31 17:23:01.505 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: ctor@[name=Thread-12, id=3914]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.506 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioRecord: ctor@[name=Thread-12, id=3914]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.506 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: ctor@[name=Thread-12, id=3914]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.507 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: init@[name=Thread-12, id=3914]
2020-10-31 17:23:01.507 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: audio mode is: MODE_NORMAL
2020-10-31 17:23:01.510 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioRecord: enableBuiltInAEC(true)
2020-10-31 17:23:01.511 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: setAEC(true)
2020-10-31 17:23:01.511 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: canUseAcousticEchoCanceler: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.511 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioRecord: enableBuiltInNS(true)
2020-10-31 17:23:01.511 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: setNS(true)
2020-10-31 17:23:01.511 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioEffects: canUseNoiseSuppressor: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.513 27928-28662/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onNetworkThreadReady
2020-10-31 17:23:01.513 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onWorkerThreadReady
2020-10-31 17:23:01.514 27928-28664/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onSignalingThreadReady
2020-10-31 17:23:01.515 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: sendLoginMessageToFreeSwitch: 
2020-10-31 17:23:01.630 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCProximitySensor: Proximity sensor => FAR state
2020-10-31 17:23:01.630 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCProximitySensor: onSensorChanged@[name=main, id=2]: accuracy=3, timestamp=156229400004732, distance=5.000305
2020-10-31 17:23:01.665 27928-27995/com.mirrorfly.dev V/WebRtcCallService callApi: sendCallApi
2020-10-31 17:23:01.687 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev I/WebRtcCallService: in onBind()
2020-10-31 17:23:01.746 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_localInitializing EglRenderer
2020-10-31 17:23:01.748 27928-28688/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_localEglBase.create shared context
2020-10-31 17:23:01.748 27928-28688/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglBase14: SDK version: 28. isEGL14Supported: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.751 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_remoteInitializing EglRenderer
2020-10-31 17:23:01.753 27928-28689/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_remoteEglBase.create shared context
2020-10-31 17:23:01.753 27928-28689/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglBase14: SDK version: 28. isEGL14Supported: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.757 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_localsetMirror: true
2020-10-31 17:23:01.757 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_remotesetMirror: false
2020-10-31 17:23:01.948 27928-28106/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_localDuration: 4005 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:01.948 27928-28108/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_remoteDuration: 4006 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:02.770 27928-27995/com.mirrorfly.dev V/WebRtcCallService callApi try: 200
2020-10-31 17:23:03.454 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handleMessage: {"type":"switch_event","from":"freeswitch","payload":{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"message":"logged in","sessid":"7e16bf86-1926-4437-8345-9e9a232aae9d"}}}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.455 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handlePayloadEventFromFreeswitch: payload: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"message":"logged in","sessid":"7e16bf86-1926-4437-8345-9e9a232aae9d"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.456 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRtcCallService: broadcastFreeSwitchCallEventMessage: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"message":"logged in","sessid":"7e16bf86-1926-4437-8345-9e9a232aae9d"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.458 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handleMessage: {"from":"freeswitch_remote","type":"init"}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.476 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handleMessage: {"type":"switch_event","from":"freeswitch","payload":{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":21,"method":"verto.clientReady","params":{"reattached_sessions":[]}}}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.477 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handlePayloadEventFromFreeswitch: payload: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":21,"method":"verto.clientReady","params":{"reattached_sessions":[]}}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.478 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRtcCallService: broadcastFreeSwitchCallEventMessage: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":21,"method":"verto.clientReady","params":{"reattached_sessions":[]}}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.491 27928-28662/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: NetworkMonitor: Start monitoring with native observer 532555232320
2020-10-31 17:23:03.498 27928-28662/com.mirrorfly.dev W/org.webrtc.Logging: NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: Unable to obtain permission to request a cellular network.
2020-10-31 17:23:03.507 27928-28119/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: Network becomes available: 110
2020-10-31 17:23:03.518 27928-28119/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: capabilities changed: [ Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED Unwanted:  LinkUpBandwidth>=1048576Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=1048576Kbps SignalStrength: -54 SSID: "JB"]
2020-10-31 17:23:03.530 27928-28119/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: link properties changed: {InterfaceName: wlan0 LinkAddresses: [****]  Routes: [fe80::/64 -> :: wlan0,192.168.0.0/24 -> 0.0.0.0 wlan0,0.0.0.0/0 -> 192.168.0.1 wlan0,] DnsAddresses: [192.168.0.1,] UsePrivateDns: false PrivateDnsServerName: null Domains: null MTU: 0 TcpBufferSizes: 524288,1048576,5505024,262144,524288,4194304}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.533 27928-28664/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: onIceCandidate: getLocalDescriptionv=0
    o=- 2369454492937584492 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
    s=-
    t=0 0
    a=group:BUNDLE audio
    a=msid-semantic: WMS
    m=audio 39302 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
    c=IN IP4 192.168.0.147
    a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    a=candidate:391698111 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.0.147 39302 typ host generation 0 network-id 3 network-cost 10
    a=ice-ufrag:c1je
    a=ice-pwd:hmYZJI6KiwAabJz9qCH8Fl/T
    a=ice-options:trickle renomination
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 97:56:F9:94:58:19:F3:D8:63:DB:C5:63:C3:72:64:65:B6:1F:24:47:3D:F3:36:52:8F:28:67:F1:BE:70:7D:E3
    a=setup:actpass
    a=mid:audio
    a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
    a=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
    a=sendrecv
    a=msid:- ARDAMSa0
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
    a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
    a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
    a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
    a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
    a=rtpmap:102 ILBC/8000
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
    a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
    a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
    a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
    a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
    a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
    a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
    a=ssrc:436866160 cname:TTaXNRQq+i+TH2GF
    a=ssrc:436866160 msid: ARDAMSa0
    a=ssrc:436866160 mslabel:
    a=ssrc:436866160 label:ARDAMSa0
2020-10-31 17:23:03.909 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handleMessage: {"type":"switch_event","from":"freeswitch","payload":{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":4,"result":{"message":"CALL CREATED","callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","sessid":"7e16bf86-1926-4437-8345-9e9a232aae9d"}}}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.910 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handlePayloadEventFromFreeswitch: payload: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":4,"result":{"message":"CALL CREATED","callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","sessid":"7e16bf86-1926-4437-8345-9e9a232aae9d"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:03.911 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRtcCallService: broadcastFreeSwitchCallEventMessage: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":4,"result":{"message":"CALL CREATED","callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","sessid":"7e16bf86-1926-4437-8345-9e9a232aae9d"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:05.756 27928-28688/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_localDuration: 4004 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:05.761 27928-28689/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_remoteDuration: 4004 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:05.952 27928-28108/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_remoteDuration: 4003 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:05.952 27928-28106/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_localDuration: 4003 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:09.761 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handleMessage: {"type":"switch_event","from":"freeswitch","payload":{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":23,"method":"verto.answer","params":{"callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","sdp":"v=0\r\no=FreeSWITCH 1604125657 1604125658 IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\ns=FreeSWITCH\r\nc=IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo\r\nm=audio 19532 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 110\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event\/48000\r\na=silenceSupp:off - - - -\r\na=ptime:20\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 E5:8A:6F:B2:1B:B2:B9:FC:C7:11:3A:61:42:DC:9D:37:E9:07:47:DE:D8:2E:98:36:D8:DE:A9:31:6D:38:FA:86\r\na=setup:active\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp:19532 IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\na=ice-ufrag:a7pxEmornVU1fmfK\r\na=ice-pwd:UEiqteweDVhVRN3RLiffutxH\r\na=candidate:3297344421 1 udp 659136 52.53.75.119 19532 typ host generation 0\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=ssrc:933318791 cname:FIzIFY6gUyydr6Gi\r\na=ssrc:933318791 msid:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo a0\r\na=ssrc:933318791 mslabel:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo\r\na=ssrc:933318791 label:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCoa0\r\n"}}}
2020-10-31 17:23:09.762 27928-28688/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_localDuration: 4006 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:09.763 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handlePayloadEventFromFreeswitch: payload: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":23,"method":"verto.answer","params":{"callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","sdp":"v=0\r\no=FreeSWITCH 1604125657 1604125658 IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\ns=FreeSWITCH\r\nc=IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo\r\nm=audio 19532 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 110\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event\/48000\r\na=silenceSupp:off - - - -\r\na=ptime:20\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 E5:8A:6F:B2:1B:B2:B9:FC:C7:11:3A:61:42:DC:9D:37:E9:07:47:DE:D8:2E:98:36:D8:DE:A9:31:6D:38:FA:86\r\na=setup:active\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp:19532 IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\na=ice-ufrag:a7pxEmornVU1fmfK\r\na=ice-pwd:UEiqteweDVhVRN3RLiffutxH\r\na=candidate:3297344421 1 udp 659136 52.53.75.119 19532 typ host generation 0\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=ssrc:933318791 cname:FIzIFY6gUyydr6Gi\r\na=ssrc:933318791 msid:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo a0\r\na=ssrc:933318791 mslabel:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo\r\na=ssrc:933318791 label:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCoa0\r\n"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:09.764 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRtcCallService: broadcastFreeSwitchCallEventMessage: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":23,"method":"verto.answer","params":{"callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","sdp":"v=0\r\no=FreeSWITCH 1604125657 1604125658 IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\ns=FreeSWITCH\r\nc=IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo\r\nm=audio 19532 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 110\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event\/48000\r\na=silenceSupp:off - - - -\r\na=ptime:20\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 E5:8A:6F:B2:1B:B2:B9:FC:C7:11:3A:61:42:DC:9D:37:E9:07:47:DE:D8:2E:98:36:D8:DE:A9:31:6D:38:FA:86\r\na=setup:active\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp:19532 IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\na=ice-ufrag:a7pxEmornVU1fmfK\r\na=ice-pwd:UEiqteweDVhVRN3RLiffutxH\r\na=candidate:3297344421 1 udp 659136 52.53.75.119 19532 typ host generation 0\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=ssrc:933318791 cname:FIzIFY6gUyydr6Gi\r\na=ssrc:933318791 msid:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo a0\r\na=ssrc:933318791 mslabel:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo\r\na=ssrc:933318791 label:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCoa0\r\n"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:09.765 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: remoteSDP: 
    v=0
    o=FreeSWITCH 1604125657 1604125658 IN IP4 52.53.75.119
    s=FreeSWITCH
    c=IN IP4 52.53.75.119
    t=0 0
    a=msid-semantic: WMS Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo
    m=audio 19532 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 110
    a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
    a=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10
    a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
    a=silenceSupp:off - - - -
    a=ptime:20
    a=sendrecv
    a=fingerprint:sha-256 E5:8A:6F:B2:1B:B2:B9:FC:C7:11:3A:61:42:DC:9D:37:E9:07:47:DE:D8:2E:98:36:D8:DE:A9:31:6D:38:FA:86
    a=setup:active
    a=rtcp-mux
    a=rtcp:19532 IN IP4 52.53.75.119
    a=ice-ufrag:a7pxEmornVU1fmfK
    a=ice-pwd:UEiqteweDVhVRN3RLiffutxH
    a=candidate:3297344421 1 udp 659136 52.53.75.119 19532 typ host generation 0
    a=end-of-candidates
    a=ssrc:933318791 cname:FIzIFY6gUyydr6Gi
    a=ssrc:933318791 msid:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo a0
    a=ssrc:933318791 mslabel:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo
    a=ssrc:933318791 label:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCoa0
2020-10-31 17:23:09.767 27928-28689/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: EglRenderer: view_video_remoteDuration: 4005 ms. Frames received: 0. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:09.767 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handleMessage: {"from":"freeswitch_remote","type":"answer","payload":{"sdp":"v=0\r\no=FreeSWITCH 1604125657 1604125658 IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\ns=FreeSWITCH\r\nc=IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo\r\nm=audio 19532 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 110\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=fmtp:111 useinbandfec=1; minptime=10\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event\/48000\r\na=silenceSupp:off - - - -\r\na=ptime:20\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 E5:8A:6F:B2:1B:B2:B9:FC:C7:11:3A:61:42:DC:9D:37:E9:07:47:DE:D8:2E:98:36:D8:DE:A9:31:6D:38:FA:86\r\na=setup:active\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp:19532 IN IP4 52.53.75.119\r\na=ice-ufrag:a7pxEmornVU1fmfK\r\na=ice-pwd:UEiqteweDVhVRN3RLiffutxH\r\na=candidate:3297344421 1 udp 659136 52.53.75.119 19532 typ host generation 0\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=ssrc:933318791 cname:FIzIFY6gUyydr6Gi\r\na=ssrc:933318791 msid:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo a0\r\na=ssrc:933318791 mslabel:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCo\r\na=ssrc:933318791 label:Klflc7yyL6Crs3HD0eBgxG70XbHCNuCoa0\r\n","type":"answer"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:09.777 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: initPlayout(sampleRate=48000, channels=1)
2020-10-31 17:23:09.777 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: byteBuffer.capacity: 960
2020-10-31 17:23:09.779 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize: 7688
2020-10-31 17:23:09.780 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: createAudioTrackOnLollipopOrHigher
2020-10-31 17:23:09.780 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: nativeOutputSampleRate: 48000
2020-10-31 17:23:09.798 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrack: session ID: 2753, channels: 1, sample rate: 48000, max gain: 1.0
2020-10-31 17:23:09.799 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrack: buffer size in frames: 3844
2020-10-31 17:23:09.799 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrack: buffer capacity in frames: 3844
2020-10-31 17:23:09.801 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: startPlayout
2020-10-31 17:23:09.808 27928-28721/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrackThread@[name=AudioTrackJavaThread, id=3935]
2020-10-31 17:23:09.812 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev I/WebRtcCallService: Attended from :freeswitch_remote Call type : audio CallerDevice : freeswitch
2020-10-31 17:23:09.814 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handleMessage: {"type":"switch_event","from":"freeswitch","payload":{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":25,"method":"verto.display","params":{"callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","display_name":"Outbound Call","display_number":"1006","caller_id_name":"","caller_id_number":"0000000000","callee_id_name":"Outbound Call","callee_id_number":"1006","display_direction":"inbound"}}}
2020-10-31 17:23:09.815 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/com.contus.webrtc.WebRtcClient: handlePayloadEventFromFreeswitch: payload: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":25,"method":"verto.display","params":{"callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","display_name":"Outbound Call","display_number":"1006","caller_id_name":"","caller_id_number":"0000000000","callee_id_name":"Outbound Call","callee_id_number":"1006","display_direction":"inbound"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:09.815 27928-28081/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRtcCallService: broadcastFreeSwitchCallEventMessage: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":25,"method":"verto.display","params":{"callID":"5551006-1604145183524-5551006","display_name":"Outbound Call","display_number":"1006","caller_id_name":"","caller_id_number":"0000000000","callee_id_name":"Outbound Call","callee_id_number":"1006","display_direction":"inbound"}}
2020-10-31 17:23:11.686 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev V/WebRtcCallService: callingstatusRunnable 
2020-10-31 17:23:11.687 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev V/WebRtcCallService: callingstatusRunnable --- Calling... 
     Trying to Connect Dropped: 0. Rendered: 0. Render fps: 0.0. Average render time: NA. Average swapBuffer time: NA.
2020-10-31 17:23:21.588 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev I/WebRtcCallService: Service started#onStartCommand :LOCAL_HANGUP
2020-10-31 17:23:21.593 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev I/WebRtcCallService: disconnectCall() called
2020-10-31 17:23:21.635 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: stop: BT state=2
2020-10-31 17:23:21.636 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: stopScoAudio: BT state=2, SCO is on: false
2020-10-31 17:23:21.637 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: cancelTimer
2020-10-31 17:23:21.638 27928-27928/com.mirrorfly.dev D/WebRTCBluetoothManager: stop done: BT state=0
2020-10-31 17:23:21.675 27928-28664/com.mirrorfly.dev V/WebRtcCallService: sendEndedMessage called if --  true
2020-10-31 17:23:21.679 27928-27995/com.mirrorfly.dev V/WebRtcCallService callApi: sendCallApi
2020-10-31 17:23:21.699 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: stopPlayout
2020-10-31 17:23:21.699 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: underrun count: 1
2020-10-31 17:23:21.700 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: stopThread
2020-10-31 17:23:21.700 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: Stopping the AudioTrackThread...
2020-10-31 17:23:21.731 27928-28721/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: Calling AudioTrack.stop...
2020-10-31 17:23:21.732 27928-28721/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrack.stop is done.
2020-10-31 17:23:21.733 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrackThread has now been stopped.
2020-10-31 17:23:21.733 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioTrack: releaseAudioResources
2020-10-31 17:23:21.740 27928-28662/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: NetworkMonitor: Stop monitoring with native observer 532555232320
2020-10-31 17:23:21.740 27928-28662/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: NetworkMonitorAutoDetect: Unregister network callback
2020-10-31 17:23:21.759 27928-28663/com.mirrorfly.dev I/org.webrtc.Logging: WebRtcAudioManager: dispose@[name=Thread-12, id=3914]
```

Changed my stun and turn servers too.
But still same problem.

Comment: Do you allow access to the FreeSWITCH RTP ports on your firewall? ` a=candidate:3297344421 1 udp 659136 52.53.75.119 19532 typ host generation 0` means the remote peer needs to be able to reach `52.53.75.119:19532` on your FS box.

Comment: solved that issue bro i was forwarding sdp without ice cadnditates to freeswitch

Comment: Hey @Jeeva, Can you please assist in this issue?

I am having the same issue, but in my case, it acts like `unidirectional` communication. Your assistance might help us.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435395/freeswitch-mode-verto-webrtc-android-unable-to-make-call-from-android

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanBashir bro suggested what i did in my code hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. @Jeeva Is there any possibility that you can give me 10-15minutes on google meet, that would be really helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sharing my sdp to sip trunk immeditely once sdp got generated which did not contain ice candidates gathered.so i waited to 2-5 seconds and forwarded my sdp which contained sdp with ice candidates and audio started flowing.
Did the same while answering the calls in verto.answer.gave 2 seconds delay to reply so i can send verto.answer with sdp which contained ice candidates gathered.